# React Native listen all input

Tags: react-native

First, thank you for taking the time to read and help.

We have a third party barcode scanner on an android device. The device reads the barcode and sends the data back as keyboard input. I have been looking for a way to just capture all text input, but I haven't been able to find a global text input listener.

Does anyone know a way I can do this without forcing the user to click into the input box (ideally I would just capture and never present the input to the user), and then scanning the barcode?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is to capture the raw keyboard events.  It's the same as getting input from an external usb/bluetooth keyboard.  You are correct that this won't work without a native module to capture those system-level events.

This react native library can do the trick:
https://github.com/kevinejohn/react-native-keyevent