# Handling Physical Barcode Scanner input in TextInput

Tags: react-native, barcode-scanner

I'm trying to capture the barcode scanner data from a physical device which connected from Bluetooth to a TextInput in my react native app.

When scanned, TextInpt onChangeText is fired only for only upto 1 character from the beginning (barcode length is 10). And I'm expecting the barcode scanner will fire the enter event and the onSubmitEditing is firing. But it's not.

Eg: If the barcode is ABCDSDF-124445 this only get the first character (A only) as the barcode.

Here is my TextInput with set useState functions

```
const [barcodeNo, setBarcodeNo] = useState('');

const changeBarcode = (barcode) => {
    // some validations
    setBarcodeNo(barcode);
}

const submitBarcode = () => {
    handleBarcodeScan(barcodeNo);
    setBarcodeNo('');
}

<Input
    value={barcodeNo}
    onChangeText={changeBarcode}
    onSubmitEditing={submitBarcode}
/>
```

I'm so thankful if you can help me to solve this issue

Comment: should the scanner start scanning when you click on the input? that's not clear

Comment: @RowanX scanner starts when I focus the TextInput and then scan the Barcode from the Barcode Scanner

Comment: This article may be helpful. [React Native listen all input](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62688350/9014308)